# Cannot bind to the target method because ... from Delegate.Create(..) + Reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, async-await, system.reflection

```
public class AwaitableRoutedEvent
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs;

    public async Task When<TypeOfControl>(TypeOfControl source, string nameOfEvent)
    {
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        var targetEventInfo = source.GetType().GetEvent(nameOfEvent);
        Delegate tempEventHandler =
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                targetEventInfo.EventHandlerType,
                GetType().GetMethod(nameof(RoutedEventHandler), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));

        try
        {
            targetEventInfo.AddEventHandler(source, tempEventHandler);

            await _tcs.Task;
        }
        finally
        {
            targetEventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(source, tempEventHandler);
            _tcs = null;
        }
    }

    public void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs arguments)
    {
        _tcs.TrySetResult(null);
    }
}
```

The calss above represents an 'awaitable' `RoutedEventHandler` event. The goal is to use it like `await new AwaitableRoutedEvent().When(button_object, "click");`.

**IF I MAKE `public void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs arguments)` STATIC**... and change `BindingsFlags`... it works. But I don't like static. Non-static version throws an exception: `Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type`.

Did I miss something?

Comment: If you've found the solution to your problem you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, but `async/await` compiles it's state machine to a static instance. I think that's why it requires you to use a `static` method. Maybe in latest version of C#7 it behaves differently, but I'm not sure about that. Did you try to disassemble your code.

Comment: @VMAtm no, your are wrong. I just used some other overload of Delega.Create(...) and that was fine. I did not dig into MSIL since have a lot to do now, byt in the nearest future I'd like to discover that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because RoutedEventHandler is an instance method, when creating a delegate you should supply an instance of the object on which the method is invoked:

```
Delegate tempEventHandler =
        Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            targetEventInfo.EventHandlerType,
            this,
            GetType().GetMethod(nameof(RoutedEventHandler), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));
```

And seemingly you do not need that at all because you may write

```
RoutedEventHandler tempEventHandler = this.MyRoutedEventhander;

public void MyRoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs arguments)
{
    _tcs.TrySetResult(null);
}
```